# How to use T2A with newtxtext?

Tags: font-encodings, cyrillic, newtx

The **MWE** below produces a warning

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T2A/ntxtlf/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `T2A/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 4.
```

I tried to locally change the font to CMR but no success. So, how to fix it?

### MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}
\newcommand{\ru}{\selectlanguage{russian}}

\begin{document}
\ru Інститут математики
\end{document}
```